# Python: Can not write to CSV file

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x

I have this snippet of Python code:

```
import csv

def analyse(csvFileToRead, csvFileToWrite):
    # open file to read
    openedCsvFileToRead = open(csvFileToRead)
    reader = csv.reader(openedCsvFileToRead)

    # open file to write
    openedCsvFileToWrite = open(csvFileToWrite)
    writer = csv.writer(openedCsvFileToWrite)

    for row in reader:
        date = row[8]
        if date[0] == "5":
            writer.writerow(row)

    # close file
    openedCsvFileToRead.close()
    openedCsvFileToWrite.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    analyse("mydata.csv", "mynewdata.csv")
```

when run using Python 3.4  I get the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 40, in <module>
    analyse("mydata.csv", "mynewdata.csv")
  File "main.py", line 25, in analyse
    writer.writerow(row)
io.UnsupportedOperation: not writable
```

What Am I doing wrong? 
I'm on Windows 7 64bit.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You have to open the file in write mode:

```
openedCSvFileToWrite = open(csvFileToWrite, "w")
```

Note that in Python 2.x, the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) always use `'wb'`, rather than `'w'`.

Comment: thanks worked, I totally never thought of that. I really deserve a down vote.

Comment: @Amani: This is a correct question. If everyone understood everything, there would be no StackOverflow ;)